# Having trouble moving program from python to Mathematica

Tags: code-request, python, stochastic-calculus, system-modeling

I'm trying to move a Covid-19 model programmed in python to Mathematica and I can't figure out how to translate this segment of the code to Mathematica.

```
def maxhosp(Ntest, f=1.0):
# Total population, N.
N = 31914989
# Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
I0, Q0, R0 = 1000, 0, 0
# Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
S0 = N - I0 - R0 - Q0
# Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
beta, gamma = 1./6.0, 1.0/15.0 
# A grid of time points (in days)
t = np.linspace(0, 365, 365)
# The SIR model differential equations.
posrate=0.8
hosprate = 0.13
def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
    S, I, Q, R = y
    dSdt = -beta * S * I / N
    dIdt = beta * S * I / N - Ntest* f*posrate* I/N - gamma * I
    dQdt = Ntest* f*posrate* I/N - gamma * Q
    dRdt = gamma * (I+Q)
    return dSdt, dIdt, dQdt, dRdt
# Initial conditions vector
y0 = S0, I0, Q0, R0
# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
S, I, Q, R = ret.T
return np.max(hosprate*(I+Q)/N)
ntests = np.logspace(3, np.log10(20e6), 300)
sims1 = [maxhosp(n, f=1.0) for n in ntests]
sims3 = [maxhosp(n, f=3.0) for n in ntests]
sims10 = [maxhosp(n, f=10.0) for n in ntests]
sims30 = [maxhosp(n, f=30.0) for n in ntests]
# plot in frac of population
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.axhline(0.01, color='r', lw=1, linestyle='-', label='#camas en \nel Perú')
ax.plot(ntests/1e6, np.array(sims1)*N/1e6, lw=2, label='$f=1.0$')
```

Is it possible to create a function like maxhosp that takes ntest and f as inputs and returns the max value hosprate*(I+Q)/N for each given n and be able to graph it?

Comment: What you are asking is undoubtedly possible, but I don’t read Python, so can you explain what `maxhosp` should do and how it is applied, ad to what kind of data? It seems to me that you would be carrying out some sort of `Map` operation, in which you carry out a similar operation on all members of an array, using each item as input to your function in turn. If you want two paired inputs, then look at `Fold`. If you want all possible combinations of inputs, then probably `Outer` would help.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could describe your model in the abstract; perhaps an idiomatic Mathematica approach could be very achieved more easily.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are solving some ODEs, in WM you can use `DSolve[]` or `NDSolve[]` functions to do this, just look at the documentation for there functions. Also, try to search WM code for epidemic dynamics, like https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SIREpidemicDynamics/ looks similar.

Comment: Is there any part of this that you can do yourself? Defining the variables, at least? Make an attempt with `NDSolve`? For what it's worth, [here](http://wolframlanguagereviews.org/2020/03/31/modelling-covid-19-with-seir/) is an example of how to solve a similar model with `NDSolve`.

Comment: If you already have the python program, why do you need a Mathematica version? In other words, what is the context of your question?